# TypeORM in nestjs: How to fetch relations with single table inheritance via repository with typescript

Tags: typescript, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I have models with inheritance and I want to fetch relations `@ManyToOne` which also have relations in it over a repository. The models/entities are much more complex in my use case as in the following examples.

From the classes below I want to select the `link` and `ref` objects over the entries repository like

```
entriesRepository.findOne({
  relations: {
    entry: {
       link = true,
       ref = true
    }
  },
  where: { id },
});
```

But because ref and link are in the inherited, the code snippet above will not compile in typescript.

```
@Entity()
export class Entries {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @ManyToOne(() => AbstractParent, { cascade: false })
  entry: AbstractParent ;
}

@Entity()
@TableInheritance({ column: { type: "varchar", name: "type" } })
export abstract class AbstractParent {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  title: string;
}

@ChildEntity()
export class ChildA extends AbstractParent {
    OneToOne(() => LinkToSomething, { cascade: true })
    @JoinColumn()
    link: LinkToSomething;
}

@ChildEntity()
export class ChildB extends AbstractParent {
    OneToOne(() => SomeReference, { cascade: true })
    @JoinColumn()
    ref: SomeReference;
}
```

I've also tried to use `createQueryBuilder` with no success.

What's the right way to do something like this?